# IE8 javascript scoping weirdness with named function expressions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Can anyone explain what's going on here:

```
(function () { 
    this.bob = function bob() {};

    window.alert(typeof(bob) + ', ' + typeof(this.bob) + ', ' + (bob == this.bob));
})();
```

The output - if you run this in IE8 - is:

`function, function, false`

Other browsers will give:

`function, function, true` - as you would expect!

As far as I've been able to gather the scoping works differently in IE8.

In other browsers, `bob` and `this.bob`, on the last line, are the same reference, because `this` is the window - i.e. the global scope - and `bob` refers to a global variable.

In IE8 though - I believe - `bob` is a local reference, as defined by `function bob`.

Even if this is the case though, surely both references refer to the same `function` object and so `bob == this.bob` should still return true??

Does anyone have sufficiently in depth knowledge of IE8 to explain this behaviour?

Comment: Nope, IE8 creates a global `bob` too. Other browsers are treating `this.bob` and `bob` in the function as the same reference, as it should be. http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: That explains it - thanks @Teemu! Post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct - but I guess you don't need the reputation..?! :-)

Comment: Wait! There's something [wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/zg512xjf/) ...

Comment: Hmm.. it's your example, where `this` refers to `window` ...

Comment: You've changed your first comment slightly @Teemu. I didn't mean to imply that IE8 wasn't creating a global `bob`. But the issue - as per your link - is that IE8 also creates a local `bob` _and assigns it to a separate function instance!_, whereas in other browsers, there is no local `bob` so `bob` is simply the global reference (whew!).

Comment: Well, `bob` and `this.bob` in your example are both global in all browsers because `this` refers to `window`. Hence they are really referring the same function. In IE8, over all this, there's the JScript mess, as explained in kangax'es article.

Comment: No, `this.bob` is global in _all_ browsers, but `bob` is _not_ global in IE8. In IE8 `bob` is a local variable which is 'leaked' into the local scope from the named function. Kangax explains this in 'JScript bugs', 'Example #1'. Also, they are not referring to the same function. They refer to 2 different functions. Kangax explains this in his 'Example #3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question - based on the [link](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) @Teemu provided:

As I explained in the question, `this` refers to the window, which is also the global scope, and so `this.bob` creates a global `bob` variable - so far, so good!

In most browsers then, `this.bob` and `bob` are semantically the same - they denote the same global reference to the same function instance. There is no local `bob`.

IE8 has two specific quirks though, around named function expressions, as used in this line of code:

```
this.bob = function bob() {};
```

The first quirk is that the name of the function 'leaks' into the local scope - becoming a new local variable. So `bob` in the next line of code no longer denotes the global `bob` variable - it now denotes a separate local `bob` variable instead.

The second quirk is that in IE8, when you assign a named function expression to a variable as above, IE8 *actually creates 2 function instances!*, so `this.bob` does *not* equal the instance referred to by the local `bob`!